# SQL Compare deployment scripts do not include all ALTER SCHEMA commands

Tags: sql-server, redgate, sqlcompare

I have a database that I am trying to clean up on SQL Server 2008 (not R2). Currently, all tables reside in the dbo schema. Some table names are singular, others are plural.

I created a new schema, crm. I moved all of the tables from dbo to crm and I renamed the singular table names to match the plural table names. When I perform the SQL Compare (version 10.4.8.87) between my development database and production, the script includes the following:

```
PRINT N'Creating schemata' 
GO 
CREATE SCHEMA [crm] 
AUTHORIZATION [dbo] 
GO 

... 

(removes foreign key constraints, notice it removes them from the plural tables in dbo schema) 

PRINT N'Dropping foreign keys from [dbo].[CustomersCommittees]' 
GO 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomersCommittees] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_CustCom_ComID] 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomersCommittees] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_CustCom_CustID] 
GO 

... 

EXEC sp_rename N'[dbo].[Customer]',N'Customers',N'OBJECT' 
ALTER SCHEMA [crm] TRANSFER [dbo].[Customers] 
EXEC sp_rename N'[dbo].[CustomerAddress]',N'Addresses',N'OBJECT' 
ALTER SCHEMA [crm] TRANSFER [dbo].[Addresses] 
EXEC sp_rename N'[dbo].[Committee]',N'Committees',N'OBJECT' 
ALTER SCHEMA [crm] TRANSFER [dbo].[Committees] 

... 

(adds foreign key contraints back, notice how it adds them to the plural tables in the new crm schema, but never included a statement to ALTER SCHEMA) 

PRINT N'Adding foreign keys to [crm].[CustomersCommittees]' 
GO 
ALTER TABLE [crm].[CustomersCommittees] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CustCom_ComID] FOREIGN KEY             ([CommitteeID]) REFERENCES [reference].[Committees] ([CommitteeID]) 
ALTER TABLE [crm].[CustomersCommittees] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CustCom_CustID] FOREIGN KEY ([CustomerID]) REFERENCES [crm].[Customers] ([CustomerID]) 
GO 

...
```

As mentioned above, it does not include any of the ALTER SCHEMA ... TRANSFER ... commands for the tables that were already plural and do not need the sp_rename command to be executed.

Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I could answer more accurately if I know how SQL Compare handles these other tables... in other words, do further modifications need to be made, do the tables need to be rebuilt, or are they ignored altogether?

For the tables that are being transferred in the way you like, is it because you used schema mapping to force SQL Compare to map dbo to crm?